# Compile DLL for SQLite extension - xerial/sqlite-jdbc driver - for unionvtab and swarmvtab

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, dbeaver

I did compile successfully the extension(s) DLL using command line on VS2019.
( Tools / Comand Line / Developer CMD )

Original dir content:
shell.c
sqlite3.c
sqlite3.h
sqlite3ext.h
unionvtab.c

Command:

```
cl unionvtab.c /link /dll /out:unionvtab.dll
```

Dir content - successful build:

shell.c
sqlite3.c
sqlite3.h
sqlite3ext.h
unionvtab.c
unionvtab.dll
unionvtab.exp
unionvtab.lib
unionvtab.obj

Using sqlite3.exe:

```
sqlite> .tables
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('C:/...some dirs.../unionvtab');
sqlite> PRAGMA module_list;
swarmvtab
zipfile
unionvtab
completion
fsdir
sqlite_stmt
json_tree
json_each
fts4aux
fts3
fts4
sqlite_dbptr
fts3tokenize
sqlite_dbdata
generate_series
fts5vocab
dbstat
fts5
rtree
rtree_i32
sqlite_dbpage
sqlite> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE temp.xxx USING swarmvtab ("SELECT 'C:\users\username\dirname\dbname','tablename',0,999999999");
sqlite> .tables
temp.xxx
sqlite> select somecolumn from xxx where somecolumn = '000900000';
000900000
sqlite>
```

All worked perfectly.

When I try (in DBEAVER):

```
SELECT load_extension('C:/...some dirs.../unionvtab');
```

I get:

```
    org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
    )
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
        at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:857)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.exec(CoreStatement.java:80)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:53)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:330)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:130)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:513)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$0(SQLQueryJob.java:444)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:171)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:431)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:816)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3440)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:118)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:171)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:116)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4718)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: DBeaver runs on Java, which is most likely running on a 64-bit JVM. Did you compile it for 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: By default the VS2019 cl produce 64bit code. The sqlite3.exe I used for successful test was 64bit. Looks like the DBeaver answer the call with 32bit interface - which I'm not sure how to match - if that's even possible.